# ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from 'profiles.models'

Tags: python, django

This is kind of strange import error as I am 95% sure I didn't make any spelling mistake. I made two app one named products and other is profiles. I imported Profile class from profiles.models inside products model and made foreignkey. No problem in here. everything was running smoothly until I imported Product class from products.models inside profiles.models. I got this error

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/ECOM_ONE/Ecommerce/profiles/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    from products.models import Product
  File "/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/ECOM_ONE/Ecommerce/products/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from profiles.models import Profile
ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from 'profiles.models' (/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/ECOM_ONE/Ecommerce/profiles/models.py)
```

It saying `ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from 'profiles.models'`
here is my profiles.models

```
import uuid
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

#from products.models import Product


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """Default user for stalker_project."""

    #: First and last name do not cover name patterns around the globe
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    
 
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER = [
        ('NONE', 'none'),
        ('MALE', 'male'),
        ('FEMALE', 'female')
    ]
    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, default='NONE')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = self.user.id
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.first_name:
            return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
        else:
            return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Get url for user's detail view.

        Returns:
            str: URL for user detail."""

        return reverse("profiles:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.username.lower()})


class Wallet(models.Model):
    """ virtual wallet model for each user """
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='wallet')
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.slug}-B:{self.balance}"

class BoughtProduct(models.Model):
    #product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=0)
    active_for_resell = models.BooleanField(default=False)


# signal to create profile for user created
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        Wallet.objects.create(user=instance.profile, balance=200)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
    instance.profile.wallet.save()
```

and here is products.models

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models import Avg, Count, Sum
from mptt.fields import TreeForeignKey
from mptt.models import MPTTModel

from profiles.models import Profile 


class Category(MPTTModel):
    STATUS = (
        ('True', 'True'),
        ('False', 'False'),
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    image=models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='images/')
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['title']
    """
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    """
    def __str__(self):                           # __str__ method elaborated later in
        full_path = [self.title]                  # post.  use __unicode__ in place of
        k = self.parent
        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.title)
            k = k.parent
        return ' / '.join(full_path[::-1])



class Product(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('True', 'True'),
        ('False', 'False'),
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #many to one relation with Category
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/', null=True, default='default-book.jpg')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=0)
    amount=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title   

    @property
    def get_total_review(self):
        total_review = self.review_set.count()
        return total_review

    @property
    def get_total_rating(self):
        total_rating = self.review_set.annotate(total_rating=Sum('rating')).aggregate(Avg('total_rating'))
        return total_rating['total_rating__avg']
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:product_detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})


class Review(models.Model):
    Rating_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Poor(1)'),
    (2, 'Average(2)'),
    (3, 'Good(3)'),
    (4, 'Very Good(4)'),
    (5, 'Excellent(5)')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=Rating_CHOICES, default=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In 12th line of profiles.models if I comment out the line `from products.models import Product` no error occurs, but with this line I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from 'profiles.models'` this error. where I am doing wrong. Can't I exchange classes between two models?

Comment: You likely make a cyclic import where two modules aim to import each other.

Comment: Try `from .models import Profile`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I solve this cyclic import? or this type of import prohibited in python?

Comment: @Freemium Profile is in profiles app. So .models won't work inside products app

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. What I was doing wrong is making cyclic import between profiles and products app models. I had to import Product inside BoughtProduct model to avoid this error. Change I made is below

````
class BoughtProduct(models.Model):
    from products.models import Product  #imported Product after Profile model loading is completed
    
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=0)
    active_for_resell = models.BooleanField(default=False) ```
````

Comment: I think you missed a [section in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). Also I'm quite surpised that works as it still in declaration time, I would expect the import to be executed.